# Auto-Resize photos with html (not css?)

Tags: html, image, resize

The company I use for my website (WordPress based) has an "auto blog" but some of the posts have images that are way too large for the screen. I would like to be able to paste in a code to make sure that the long edge is only, say 500px, but keeps the ratio correct. I am a novice, so please let me know where on the page to paste the code as well. THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!
http://embarkre.com/category/real-estate-news

Sample code:

```html
<div>
<p class="subtitle">ESCAPE One is a road-ready tiny home with 276 square feet of adaptable space.</p>

<figure><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dwell-ugc/photos/6063391372700811264/6301479718082105344/large.jpg" alt="" width="700" height="467" /></figure>
<div>

For those looking to downsize, Wisconsin-based builder of tiny homes-on-wheels <a href="http://www.escapetraveler.net/" target="_blank">ESCAPE</a> has launched its latest unit, the <a href="http://www.escapetraveler.net/model-one" target="_blank">ESCAPE One</a>. The 276-square-foot Park Model RV resembles a minimalist cottage with a shou-sugi-ban exterior and clean, pine interiors, and can sleep up to four people.

</div>
<figure><a href="https://www.dwell.com/article/hit-the-road-with-this-shou-sugi-ban-trailer-asking-just-under-dollar50k-d5961fd8/6301479715116331008"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dwell-ugc/photos/6063391372700811264/6301479715116331008/large.jpg" alt="" width="1600" height="1066" /></a>
<figcaption>ESCAPE RV/Steve Niedorf </figcaption></figure>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following inside the HEAD section of your HTML.

```
<style>
  img {
    max-width: 500px;
    height: auto;
  }
</style>
```